# Intersection of radical ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to show the intersection of radical ideals is radical. Let $A$ and $B$ be radical ideals, and let $x\in\text{ rad } (A\cap B)$. Then there is an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x^n\in A\cap B$. Where do I go from here?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to be aware that the radical of $I$ is equal to the intersection of all prime ideals $\mathfrak p \supset I$, which implies that radical ideals are characterized precisely by the property of being an intersection of prime ideals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x^n\in A\cap B\subset A$ implies that $x\in A$ since $A$ radical, the same argument shows $x\in B$.

Comment: A being radical means rad($A$)=A, and so if $x\in$ rad($A$), then $x\in A$. And if $x^n\in A$, then $x^n\in$ rad($A$), but why does this means $x\in A$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_ideal

Comment: $A$ is radical i.e $x^n\in A$ implies $x\in A$.